# ASP.NET Core Null Value Insertion - Ajax Post - Fluent Validation

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am developing an ASP.NET Core project. I am using MSSQL as a database. In my database, there is a Explanation column in my table named Inventory and this column can be left nullable. But I get an error when I leave this field blank while adding data through the project.

**FluentValidation - InventoryAdditionValidator.cs,**

```
public class InventoryAdditionValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateInventoryDto>
{
    public InventoryAdditionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.InventoryID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Demirbaş No Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.Brand).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Marka Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.Model).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Model Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.Type).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Demirbaş Tipi Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.SerialNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Seri Numarası Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.UsageCondition).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Kullanım Durumu Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.Condition).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Demirbaş Durumu Boş Bırakılamaz");
        RuleFor(x => x.Ownership).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Mülkiyet Durumu Boş Bırakılamaz");
    }
}
```

**InventoryController.cs,**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddInventory(CreateInventoryDto createInventoryDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    var id = user.Id;

    InventoryAdditionValidator validationRules = new InventoryAdditionValidator();
    ValidationResult validationResult = validationRules.Validate(createInventoryDto);
    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        createInventoryDto.CreateUser = id;
        createInventoryDto.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createInventoryDto);
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7198/api/Inventory", stringContent);
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Json(createInventoryDto);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var errors = validationResult.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return BadRequest(new { Errors = errors });
    }
}
```

**InventoryAddition.cshtml - Ajax code,**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAddInventory").click(function () {
            let value = {
                InventoryID: $("#input-qr-result").val(),
                Brand: $("#choices-single-brand").val(),
                Model: $("#txtModel").val(),
                Type: $("#choices-single-type").val(),
                SerialNo: $("#txtSerialNo").val(),
                UsageCondition: $("#choices-single-usage").val(),
                Condition: $("#choices-single-condition").val(),
                Ownership: $("#choices-single-ownership").val(),
                Explanation: $("#txtExplanation").val()
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Inventory/AddInventory",
                data: value,
                success: function () {
                    $("#order-tab").removeClass("active");
                    $("#order-tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
                    $("#delivery-tab").addClass("active");
                    $("#delivery-tab-pane").addClass("show active");

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = "/Inventory/Index";
                    }, 3000);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    var errors = xhr.responseJSON && xhr.responseJSON.errors;

                    if (!errors) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.responseText;
                        showToast(errorMessage);
                    } else {
                        showValidationErrors(errors);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function showValidationErrors(errors) {
            if (Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0) {
                errors.forEach((error) => {
                    showToast(error);
                });
            }
        }

        function showToast(error) {
            Toastify({
                text: error,
                duration: 3000,
                gravity: "top",
                position: 'right',
                backgroundColor: "#f64e60",
                stopOnFocus: true,
            }).showToast();
        }
    });
</script>
```

CreateInventoryDto.cs,

```
public class CreateInventoryDto
{
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public int Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public int UsageCondition { get; set; }
    public int Condition { get; set; }
    public int Ownership { get; set; }
    public int CreateUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

I don't check this field with Fluent validation, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks,
Kind regards.

Comment: What error and what line of code?

Comment: Should `Explanation` be declared as `string?` to support null values?

Comment: @jaabh BadRequest error returns in the console.

Comment: @SteveWong It didn't work when I tried it as string?

Comment: Please show the Bad Request response that you received in the question. I believe the response should provide you the info what's incorrect/not going well.

Comment: The error on the console is like this, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: try seting the property to nullable string (`string?`)

Comment: OK, I solved the problem. I just updated the dto in the UI layer to string?. When I updated the Dto in the API layer, the problem was solved. I overlooked this. Thanks all.